# Google Earth Engine update band values of aggregated image to just the values depicted in brackets in the band when data type is double

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, aggregation, geography-data-type

I am trying to aggregate the hansen forest loss data from a 30 x 30 m resoltuion to 1 km x 1 km resolution, where the value of the band is the proportion of the cell coverage. I feel like I am close with the code below. It is obviously calculating the proportion (shown in the image below as the value in brackets) however, I am unsure how to actually access this information. When I export I just get the large numeric value (854562.1875 in the image below) when what I want is the "35%" (or 0.35). I know that it must have something to do with the data.type of the image but I can't work out how to update the band values. I have tried things such as .get() but maybe I am doing something wrong as it seems that both the large number and the value in brackets are stored as a single double value.

How do I update the band values with the percentage (values in brackets)?

In the image, green is the original image, while the red depicts the aggregated image.

[image]

Full code is below.

```
var forest = hansen.select('treecover2000'); // select treecover band
var forest_loss = hansen.select('lossyear').selfMask(); // select loss band
var forest_loss_5years = forest_loss.gt(16).selfMask(); // select forest loss in past 5 years

// Select the classification band.
var opClass = dataset.select('classification');

// Mosaic all of the granules into a single image.
var mosaic = opClass.mosaic();

// Create a mask to add transparency to non-oil palm plantation class pixels.
var mask = mosaic.neq(3);
var forest_30 = forest.gt(30); // select forest with canopy cover greater than 50%
var forest_minus_plantation = forest_30.where({test:mask, value:0});
var forest_loss_5years_gt30 = forest_loss_5years.where({test:forest_30, value:0}).selfMask(); // select forest loss in past 5 years massked by tree cover > 30%

Map.addLayer(forest_loss_5years_gt30, {palette:["grey","red"]},"original image",0);

var outputProjection = image.projection();
var outputScale = image.projection().nominalScale();

var aggFunction = ee.Reducer.sum();

// Compute forest area per pixel.
var forestArea = forest_loss_5years_gt30.reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 1112
    })
    // The reduce resolution returns the fraction of the pixel
    // that's covered by 30 meter forest pixels.  Convert to area
    // after the reduceResolution() call.
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the reference image.
    .reproject({
      crs: outputProjection
    });
    
  
Map.addLayer(forestArea, {palette:["grey","red"]}, 'aggregated image');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: forestArea, 
  description: "forest_loss_5years_gt30_prop",
  region: exportRegion,
  //scale: outputScale,
  crs: outputProjection.crs().getInfo(),
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value the Inspector displays as a percentage is the **mask** value of the band at that point. You can access it with `ee.Image.mask()`.

If you want to export the mask instead of the band values, just add a call to `.mask()`.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: forestArea.mask(), 
  ...
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much Kevin (I then added .selfMask() to remove all zeros)